# Matlab programming output error

Tags: matlab, math

I have been trying to solve below matlab programming question. I have tried my code, but it could not work for some cases.

Am I missing something?

**Question:**

> Write a function called integerize that takes as its input a matrix A
>   of non-negative integers of type double, and returns the name of the
>   “smallest” unsigned integer class to which A can be accurately
>   converted. If no such class exists, the string 'NONE' is returned. For
>   example, if the largest integer A is 14, then the function would
>   return 'uint8', but if the largest integer in A is 1e20, then the
>   function would return 'NONE'.

**Code:**

```
function integ=integerize(A)
integ = 'none'; 
maxValue=max(A(:));
disp(maxValue);
if maxValue <= intmax('uint8')
    integ='uint8';
elseif maxValue<=intmax('uint16')
    integ='uint16';
elseif maxValue <= intmax('uint32')
    integ='uint32'; 
elseif maxValue <= intmax('uint64')
    integ='uint64';
elseif mod(maxValue,1) ~= 0
    integ='NONE';
end
end
```

Output:

```
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) 0
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) 214
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) 255
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) 256
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) [80 380 468 413 51 549 971 245 39 376 65535]
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) 65536
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) 4294967295
Feedback: Your function performed correctly for argument(s) 4294967296
Feedback: Your function made an error for argument(s) 1.84467440737096e+19

Your solution is _not_ correct.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply initializing `integ` to `'NONE'` and remove the last test case?

```
function integ=integerize(A)
integ = 'NONE'; 
maxValue=max(A(:));
disp(maxValue);
if maxValue <= intmax('uint8')
    integ='uint8';
elseif maxValue<=intmax('uint16')
    integ='uint16';
elseif maxValue <= intmax('uint32')
    integ='uint32'; 
elseif maxValue <= intmax('uint64')
    integ='uint64';
end
end
```

Comment: @factor99 what were trying to achieve with the `mod(maxvalue, 1) ~=0 ` test ?

Answer (score 0):

```
%%Almost the same
```

function integ=integerize(A)

```
integ = 'none'; 
maxValue=max(A(:));
disp(maxValue);
if maxValue <= intmax('uint8')
    integ='uint8';
elseif maxValue<=intmax('uint16')
integ='uint16';
elseif maxValue <= intmax('uint32')
integ='uint32'; 
elseif maxValue <= intmax('uint64')
integ='uint64';
else
    integ='NONE';
end
end
```